# UAE Tourist Visa Information

Tags: visas, dubai, uae, tourist-visas

I have arranged a tourist visa of U.A.E. with 60 days validity and I can stay there up to 39 days as stated by the visa agent. I should leave at the 40th day.

Is it true if yes then how can i confirm it before travelling?

Comment: Why would you need to leave after 40 days on a 60 day visa?

Comment: Not a 60 days visa. I mean i would be travel within 60 days. I just want to say that have any 40 days visa is valid or not.

Comment: What does your visa say on it?

Comment: It should be written on the visa, and yes it is 39 days usually.